# PHP to JAVA - Database JSON

Tags: javascript, java, php

There are plenty of examples of using database records to disable certain dates (unavailable) using JSON and AJAX however for some reason, these are done in PHP. Is there reason why it isn't done in JAVA and how can I replace the PHP file with Java for the exact same result?

**checkDates.php**

```
<? php
$sql = "SELECT start from gbh_rooster_afwijkend WHERE dlnmrID = '".$_GET['dld'].
"'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$checkDates = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

  $checkDate['start'] = $row['start'];

  $checkDates[] = $checkDate;
}
echo json_encode($checkDates);

?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.getJSON('script/php/afwijkendrooster/checkDates.php?dld='+ id, function(json){dates=json;});

function checkAvailability(mydate){
    var myBadDates = dates;

            var $return=true;
            var $returnclass ="available";
            $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', mydate);

                    // start loop
            for(var x in myBadDates)
             {  

             $myBadDates = new Array( myBadDates[x]['start']);  

               for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)

                 if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
                   {
                        $return = false;
                            $returnclass= "unavailable";
                   }
              }
                          //end loop

            return [$return,$returnclass];
}
```

Comment: You can use whichever server-side language floats your boat.

Comment: In the case of Java, how would I structure it? Are there any examples to look out which doesn't involve PHP but Java

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not a code translation service.

Comment: If this PHP code came from an "example", as well, you should nuke that example site from orbit - your code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)